# Error loading Mysqldb module in Python Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-models

I am currently working on Ubuntu 14.10/Python/Django/MySQL  and encountering the following error when I try to run:

```
$python manage.py makemigrations polls
```

or

```
$python manage.py migrate polls
```

I have also tried syncdb
The error is:

> (Aaronpythonenv)aaron@aaron-N550JK:~/mysite$ python manage.py makemigrations polls
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 312, in execute
>       django.setup()
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/**init**.py", line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models(all_models)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 41, in 
>       class Permission(models.Model):
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 139, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/**init**.py", line 36, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 240, in **getitem**
>       backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
>       return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/home/aaron/Aaronpythonenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 27, in 
>       raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

I have used PIP to install mysql-python to my environment which I recieved another error. I then used  sudo apt-get command to install correct the error PIP brought up.

massive thank you in advance please let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: Be careful, if you are working in a virtualenv, apt-get will not install the library in it. Check if MySQLdb is installed in your virtualenv using the pip freeze command

Comment: @karec thank you, I have tried this. when i search through Virtualenv (and my env folder) I already have the version satisfied, everything worked fine before I inserted classes, but I am following the Django guide and coming up short

Comment: Can you update your post with the pip freeze output and your Databases section in the settings.py file ? i will take a look

Answer (score 5):

I faced somewhat similar problem. Try these steps:

1). Upgrade `pip` to the latest version.

```
sudo pip install pip --upgrade
```

2). Build the dependencies for python-mysqldb libraries:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-mysqldb
```

3). Install the Python MySQL libraries:

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it means there is no module named mysqldb.
You just need to setup the mysqldb module.
For example if you use the ubuntu, you just need to run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

and then you problem will be fixed!